Visual glitch on Android Studio (mac, external display): shuffled text
When I connect my Intel Macbook to an external display, I get some visual glitches on Android Studio. They happen sporadically, for a brief fraction of a second.
I have no glitches on any other app, which is what I find intriguing.

I know there's probably not much to do, but I was wondering if this is a known problem.
Notes:

Android Studio Koala
macOS Big Sur
Without an external display, no glitches appear, whether I'm using the integrated or discrete GPU. With the external display, the PC always enables the discrete GPU.
No emulator or background process is running on Android Studio.


Looks like a terminal encoding issue since none of the other text is modified
